# Creating immutable Hashsets in scala conditionally

Tags: scala, immutability

I have a small function which does this

```
val s = MutableHashSet[DateTime]()
if (a != null) s.add(a)
if (b != null) s.add(b)
if (c != null) s.add(c)
if (d != null) s.add(d)
s
```

I know using null is bad (and I can use option) but let us forget that for now and concentrate more upon how to make this HashSet immutable. `MutableHashSet` is the same as `scala.collection.mutable.HashSet`. I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6048937/1901744). However creating multiple `Seq` and then a hashset from it looks like too much of an overkill.

Comment: My solution would be simple: `Seq(a,b,c,d).filter(_ != null).toSet` (or, for example, `Seq(a,b,c,d).map(Option.apply).flatten.toSet` if you want to use options)

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek I like it. Can we change that map and flatten to flatMap? I guess no cause in that case we flatten first and then map here we are mapping first and then flattening. Am I right?

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek How about this if we are using options: `Seq (a,
      b,
      c,
      d).filter(_.isDefined).map(_.get).toSet`

Comment: @Sohaib That should also work, although using `.get` on `Option` usually looks suspicious (and sometimes is a warning/error using different linters, depending on settings). If you're starting with a `Seq[Option[DateTime]]`, then just `seq.flatten.toSet` should do the trick.

Comment: Instead of filter and and flatten You can also use : Seq(Option(1),Option(2),None,None,Option(5)).collect{case x : Option[Int] if x.nonEmpty => x.get}

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek Thanks. You can post that as an answer and Id mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per request, I'm moving my comment to an answer.

The easiest and most straightforward option would be:

```
Seq(a,b,c,d).filter(_ != null).toSet
```

Alternatively, you can convert elements to `Option[DateTime]` first:

```
val seq = Seq(a,b,c,d).map(Option.apply)
```

and then, once you have a `Seq[Option[DateTime]]` you can do:

```
seq.flatten.toSet
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a small and fixed number of values that you want to convert to a set, I would just use

```
Set.empty[DateTime] ++ Option(a) ++ Option(b) ++ Option(c) ++ Option(c)
```

If you have a large or variable number of values, the solution from Patryk seems the best.